# Need equations for some of weight initializers in tensorflow?

Tags: classification, tensorflow, cnn

For my CNN model I tried some of the weight initializers such as "truncated normal initializer","random normal initializer","glorot normal initializer","glorot uniform initializer", my questions are:

1- I need the equations for each of them, for the two Xavier initializers I found more than one type of equation for that I confused which one is true but for other two I didn't found any equation?

2- Is the range of values are between 0 and 1 for all of them? are they considered a gaussian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

2 - Not necessarily between 0 an 1. Example: If you see the normal glorot formulae, The sigma_i value will entirely depend on fan_in and fan_out. So, it need not be centred at 0.

EDIT 1:

[image]

EDIT 2:

[image]

[image]

Research [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) - weight initialization by Xavier

Credits: Also, check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEoyxE0GP2M&list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv&index=7&t=5s) and [this](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture6.pdf)
Hope it helps.

Comment: really thank you for your help, you deserve the bounty, but please could edit the answer and add detail about the equations? and could you tell me the reference of these equations because i need them for academic purpose?

Comment: Sure, I'm working on it

Comment: I've made the edit!! See if its any helful

Comment: Thank you dear, it's very helpful, but I need the explanation of each symbol used in the formulas, can you do edit and add them? for example what is fan_in and fan_out.

Comment: I've made the edit. Hope it's clear!

Comment: again thank you, one final question: what is the 'U' shaped symbol in last equation? please edit and add it.

Comment: Yes, Now I have added it in edit2